# Modify array of objects in JavaScript by setting the key value to one of the object's attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    0 : {
      id: 'somevalue',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '20'
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

I would like to modify the array, for example to set the key to the `id` attribute like this:

```
[
  {
    somevalue : {
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '20'
    }
  }
]
```

What would be the best way to achieve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `data.map(function(d) {
  let ref = d[0];
  let id = ref.id;
  delete ref.id;
  return {
    [id]: ref
  };
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is only one nested object, you can use the function `map` as follow:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    0 : {
      id: 'somevalue',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '20'
    }
  }
];

let result = arr.map(o => {
  let [{id, ...rest}] = Object.values(o);
  return {[id]: rest};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. All the other answers were great too! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

You could destructure the object and take the wanted key out of the object. Then return new object with wanted value.

```js
var array = [{ 0 : { id: 'somevalue', name: 'John Doe', age: '20' } }],
    key = 'id',
    result = array.map(({ 0: { [key]: k, ...o } }) => ({ [k]: o }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have just more then 1 Object. You can try it like this.

```js
let data = [
  {
    0 : {
      id: 'somevalue',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '20'
    }
  }
]


let result = data.map((el, index) => {
   let id = el[index].id;
   delete el[index].id;
   return { [id]: {...el[index]}}
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if the key is always '0' in the given object

```
const arr = [
  {
    0 : {
      id: 'somevalue',
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: '20'
    }
  }
]

arr.map(item => {
    const value = {...item[0]};
    const key = value.id;
    delete value.id;
    return {
        [key]: value
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` functions to achieve the desired output.

This solution will work even if you have more than one nested objects and if you have more properties in your nested objects, i.e. properties other than `name` and `age`

```js
const arr = [
  {
    0: { id: "somevalue", name: "John Doe", age: "20" },
    1: { id: "somevalue 2", name: "John Doe", age: "20", gender: 'male' }
  },
  {
    0: { id: "somevalue 3", name: "John Doe", age: "20" },
    1: { id: "somevalue 4", name: "John Doe", age: "20", gender: 'male' },
    2: { id: "somevalue 5", name: "John Doe", age: "20" }
  }
];

const res = arr.map((obj) => {
  const v = Object.values(obj);

  return v.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const {id, ...restProps } = curr;
    acc[curr.id] = restProps;
    
    return acc; 
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```